# How coronavirus are transmitted in New York City and in other states in the US?

Tags: disease-transmission, coronavirus, airborne-transmission

We know coronavirus is transmitted by 1) droplet in air 2) touching a physically contaminated object by a coronavirus patient and then touch our face or mouth.

**Now New York City got hit so hard, what is the primary transmission? 1) or 2) from above?**

Also, let's say you pass a coronavirus patient in the supermarket, and he does not wear mask. What you can do to protect yourself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Actually what is the main way COVID-19 spreads?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/actually-what-is-the-main-way-covid-19-spreads) Have you bothered to look at any recent questions before asking your own?

Comment: The reason NY got hit so hard was because NY has the one of highest density of people living in the world, higher than HK, and it's a major international hub. And because they were not testing for community transmission so they got hit by a tsunami of community acquired infections.